# Set background by jquery in a multiple selector

Tags: jquery

I want to set a background to a css style by jquery , the problem is that I have this selector at the .css

```
#wrapper-inside #content
{background: url("http://") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
```

At the html they are like this:

```
<div id="wrapper-inside">
                <div id="content">
```

Its possible to set by .css method a background to that rule?

Comment: Try use `$('#wrapper-inside #content').css('background', 'http://');`

Comment: there's no problem with .css, so where is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply by using .css in jQuery

```
.className{
......
}

$('#content').addClass('className');
```

If you want to add a class also you can add using **.addClass();**

Comment: But in the css file I have like: #wrapper-inside #content
{background: url("http://") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}

Is to that rule that i have to put it..

Comment: try to put that into a css class then use addclass

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follow code to change/add any css style in your element.

```
$('#content').css({background:'red'});
```

You can see an example here with **.css()** or **.addClass()**: http://jsfiddle.net/4Vdqh/2/